# How can I estimate ATT for each stratum

Tags: propensity-scores, stratification

the following code if for estimating ATT, my question is :if I want to estimate ATT for each stratum,can I use this code and how can I change it to give me ATT for each stratum?

```
Subclassification on the PS for the ATT
mS <- matchit(A ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5 + 
                 X6 + X7 + X8 + X9, data = d,
               method = "subclass", estimand = "ATT")

#Extract matched data
md <- match.data(mS)

fitS <- lm(Y_C ~ subclass * (A * (X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5 + 
                                    X6 + X7 + X8 + X9)),
           data = md)

avg_comparisons(fitS,
                variables = "A",
                vcov = "HC3",
                newdata = subset(md, A == 1))
```